# Exporting data to excel on weekly and monthly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I have an export option and dropdown to select month and week as show in image below

[image: export image]

I have start and end time in my database. But i don't know how to export based on time stamp. Please, suggest me a solution of how to do it.

Thank you in Advance!!!

Comment: Convert date to timestamp, get data `where t.timestamp >= :startTimestamp and t.timestamp <= :endTimestamp`. Save exported data to Excel using PHP libs. `mktime('2018-02-23') -> timestamp`

Comment: @Justunas can you please help me more about that because i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well, first try something by yourself

Comment: @Justinas I am able to get data to excel but i don't know where to write the time stamp so that i can get based on option i select